# User session on social website - logic question

Tags: php, database, session, codeigniter

I have a social website in developmenti n PHP codeignitor and MySQL. I am storing user sessions in the database to handle a multi-server enviornment. Currently there is only 1 database.

1) To handle multiple databases (+ the multi server) how and where will the user session be stored? I assume database wont work in a multi-database env.

2) The session ID given to the user, is it an auto increament from the database or generated from the application logic? I assume it should be a GUID?

3) Along with the session ID I have a user_session table which logs all session related details like login_datetime, logout_Datatime, if user was on web/mobile, etc. So this table has to be written to in 2 stages: When the user logs in and again when the user logsoff. The questions is when the user logsoff what is the logic the system should follow to write the date? Like how will the system know which user_session to write the data to since this PK ID is a database driven autoincreament value and created after the main session ID is created. So at end it will need to query user_session table to find the user_Session ID and then write.

Comment: Did you ever used default PHP sessions mechanism?

Comment: What storing user sessions in the database does to do with multi-server enviornment? Why defau8lt PHP sessions doesn't suits you? anyway. what's wrong with multi-database env? What particular problems do you see here?

Comment: Using memcached for sessions works quite well.

Comment: I have never used memcache to store sessions. The site is launching soon, not live yet. Storing sessions in database is if there are multiple databases and session is stored in database A then when use rlogs off 2 hours later the system needs to get the ID fromd database A vs database B. So it needs to know. Same with multiple servers. One s web server, one is image server, one is video server, etc. Each server needs to check the user's session which needs to be same because all user activity is linked to the same session

Comment: The imp aspect is i need the user's last activity datetime to write the session logoff date, hence i need to somehow know how to find the user's session when he logs off, how wil the system find it in the table?

Comment: What's wrong with videoserver? Why can't it just ask a database server for the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment gave me some clues about the best way to solve this problem for you.

First, if the site is launching soon but not live yet, the best way to solve your problem is: don't worry about this problem yet.  Just host everything on one server with one database for the time being.  Your idea, no matter how brilliant, will need to solve lots of problems with its first few real users before demand picks up enough to require more hardware.

Second, your image and video servers probably don't need a user's session information.  If a user requests a web page with a video, and they have enough access to view the web page, then you can probably just send along the video without further auth checking.  This choice will also enable you to use a content delivery network (I personally like [RackSpace Cloudfiles](http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/files/), with has a partnership with Akamai) for a much-improved user experience over using your own servers.

Good luck!

Comment: I will have multiple databases very soon because for launch i have 1 database for user data and the second in works for the data warehouse used for user analytic which will output data to the same user session. Hence I need to ensure both these database can reconize the same user session when the session is created, during the session because each user activity is mapped to the session ID and again at session end because the last activity datetime OR the user logoff is written as a session end datetime. So the only way i see then is memcache correct?

Comment: Why not have one table for user data and another table for user analytics, both in the same database?